# Why does my Magento payment method not appear in the backend

Tags: magento, module, payment

This may sound like a stupid question but I can't find the solution for this. Here's my situation:

I am developing a new payment method module for Magento according to this tutorial (http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module) but for some reason it doesn't show up in the backend. I've checked the troubleshooting that is below the tutorial but I can't find the problem.

So I started reading and reading again. And than I found this line: "Make sure that app/code/local is in include_path. "

Now is my question: where can I define this path for my own custom module?

Comment: `app/code/local` is certainly in your include path. See `app/Mage.php`.

Comment: Please add (relevant parts of) your module code to your question.

Comment: Facing the same problem any idea ?